# Java configuration windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java

One of our users is getting a message about "security" that access to site was not allowed and suggested to add the site in the security tab of the configuration window for java on their computer.

When we access the configuration as an administrator, and click on the security tab to add the url as an allowed site, the "Add" button is grayed out and not accessible.  Been doing internet searches looking for why on the one computer it will not allow user to add.  It does allow me to add on mine and I have same computer model and Windows version.

We have removed java and reinstalled, rebooting the computer in the process.

Anyone have any suggestions as to what the difference might be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you log into that computer with a different user account (perhaps yours), is the button available?